# Check In file with Javascript and REST

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, client-object-model

I am trying to check in a file from my sharepoint-hosted app with jsom and rest, but it wont work

my code look like this:

```
function checkInFile() {

    var hostUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
    currentContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var hostContext = new SP.AppContextSite(currentContext, hostUrl);
    hostweb = hostContext.get_web();
    currentContext.load(hostweb);

    currentContext.executeAsync(function(){

        url: appWebUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/style library/popup.js')/checkin(comment='Check-in comment.',checkintype=0)?@target="+ hostWebUrl + "",
        method; "POST", 
        success; successHandler,
        error; errorHandler
    });

         function successHandler() {
              $('#message').append('<br /> <div>File sucessfully checked-in</div>')
           }
           function errorHandler(sender, args) {
             $('#message').append('<br /><div>Error: Status file not check-in</div>');
           }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the host web to check in the file using REST with the cross domain javascript library as mentioned in this article [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn198245.aspx). You need to execute the query on the RequestExecutor.